# PHP function to extract a field value from a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get a value of a mysql database using a php function.
I have a database like this:

```
NAME     | EMAIL                | PASSWORD  | OTHER
-------------------------------------------------------
example  | example@example.com  | password  | other
-------------------------------------------------------
example2 | example2@example.com | password2 | other2
```

and in my PHP file I've tried to use this function:

```
function selectUserField($email, $field, $connection){
    $select_user = "SELECT '$field' FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $select_user);
    $value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $value[$field];
}

//And I try to echo the result of the function
$connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

echo selectUserField("example@example.com", "name", $connection);
```

But as result I get only the field name and not its content (for this example I get "`NAME`" and not "`example`"). How can i do to get the content of the database cell?

Comment: Wrap off quotes form column name!!

Comment: Because you're asking MySQL to return the text 'NAME' by surrounding it in single quotes, field names should be surrounded with back ticks or nothing at all so mysql understand you want a field value instead of the given text.

Comment: OH, sorry for this syntax problem.   :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No quotes around $field.

```
"SELECT $field FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thank you! (sorry for the stupid question i think)

Comment: @paolobasso Please prepare your statements, don't just select an email which the user can alter, this is highly vulnerable for SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function selectUserField($email, $field, $connection){
    $select_user = "SELECT `$field` FROM users WHERE `email`='$email' LIMIT 1"; //wrap it with ` around the field or don't wrap with anything at all
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $select_user);
    $value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $value[$field];
}

//And I try to echo the result of the function
$connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

echo selectUserField("example@example.com", "name", $connection);
```