# Using PHP how do I retrieve a certain field value from a database table and then input that single field value into a new table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, mamp

This is something I've tried... I'm using a select statement to get the id from the parent table where the email is equal to the email provided by the user. After getting the id from the parent table I want to set this id to the parent_id field in the child table to a field value in a child table.

For instance, my parent table has id, first_name, last_name, address, phone, email, picture_approval and date. Then the child table has id, child_first_name, child_last_name, and parent_id

```
// already connected to database successfully
   {
        try
        {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO parents SET
            first_name = :fname,
            last_name = :lname,
            address = :address,
            phone = :phone,
            email = :email,
            picture_approval = :picture,
            date = NOW()';

            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':fname', $_POST['g_first_name']);
            $s->bindValue(':lname', $_POST['g_last_name']);
            $s->bindValue(':address', $_POST['address']);
            $s->bindValue(':phone', $_POST['phone']);
            $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
            $s->bindValue(':picture', $_POST['pictures']);
            $s->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Error adding parent to database.';
        }
    }
//the above code works perfectly
```

But then this next part never works.

```
try 
   {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM parents WHERE email = :email";
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $s->execute();
        $s->bind_result($returned_id);

        $s->fetch();

        $fieldValue = "$returned_id";


   }
   catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $errors[] = 'Error retrieving parent.';
    }
```

Then I want to set up my INSERT INTO child statement... but not really sure how since my SELECT statement does not appear to be working right. 
I did find this [PHP function to extract a field value from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549728/php-function-to-extract-a-field-value-from-a-database) but it only outputs the value, I need it to put it into another table.

Comment: If the code is run sequentially then i would use `PDO::lastInsertID`. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: So are you using PDO or mysqli?  Because [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) is a mysqli function, not a PDO function.

Comment: Do *not* drastically modify your code in your question like that.  Doing so changes the entire question and invalidates already given answers.  You can build on your post by adding an edit with the new changes alongside what was already there, otherwise, if you have a different question, please make a new post.

Comment: My bad. I didn't see any responses when changing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fieldValue = $returned_id;
```

$returned_id shouldn't be in quotes

Comment: I tried taking the quotes away and it still did nothing for me.

Comment: I got it working. Now just having some trouble with the INSERT statement for the childs table

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually looking for the ID, use [lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

```
$s->execute();
$returned_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Then you can use it as you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to search manually. In case a parent adds two another child I want to ensure the original parent id is set to the second child... not some other parent adding their name to the database (which would be the last inserted id

Comment: You are amazing. The final code came to this   include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

       **    $sql = "SELECT id FROM parents WHERE email = :email";
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
            $s->execute();
            $returned_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
            
            $error = $returned_id;
            
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';
            exit();   **

Comment: Now I'm having trouble with the INSERT statement. I'm going to post it now

Answer (score 0):

A great way to do this is create your own function.

```
 function getParentID($conn, $email) 
        {
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM parents WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
            foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) 
                {
                    $parentIDinside = $row['id'];
                } 
            return $parentIDinside;
        }
```

Then call the function. You'll pass the database connection and the email address and the function will find the parentID that matches with that email address. This function can be modified for anything.

```
 include 'includes/db.inc.php'; //my database connection that creates a new $pdo connection

        $parentID = getParentID($pdo, $_POST['email']);
```

Now the variable $parentID stores the actual parentID from the database with the email that was provided and you can use it in an INSERT statement or anywhere else you'd like.